# A column in database store one or more values of check boxes, How i get distinct values from whole column?

Tags: mysql, checkbox, distinct, union, multiple-value

```
_imagecolumn______________________ categorycolumn_________________
image1.jpg       |     Abstract Photo,Plants Photo,Brids Photo   |
image2.jpg       |     Human Photo,Plants Photo,Brids Photo      |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I get distinct values for both these images?

> image2.jpg, image1.jpg --> Human Photo, Plants Photo, Brids Photo, Abstract Photo

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get distinct values for both columns

```
SELECT * FROM foo GROUP BY imagecolumn,categorycolumn
```